# Openpyxl not able to read Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've been trying all day to get this to work but to no avail.

What I'm looking to do:

1. Open Excel file with Openpyxl
2. Edit some colors and sum a few columns in the file
3. Save the file
4. Close file

Currently I cant even get the file to open because of this error:

```
File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert

value = expected_type(value)

TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\adoucette\OneDrive - BAKE'N JOY FOODS\Desktop\DOT Weekly Report TEST.py", line 138, in <module>

wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\adoucette\\DOT_Weekly\\DOT Weekly Sales WE " + formatted_date + ".xlsx",data_only=True)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook

reader.read()

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 299, in read

apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet

stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree

return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree

return cls(**attrib)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 74, in __init__

self.fills = fills

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 27, in __set__

seq = self.container(_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 27, in <genexpr>

seq = self.container(_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq)

File "C:\Users\adoucette\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 61, in _convert

raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))

TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

Anyone know whats going on here? See below for relevant code:

```
now = datetime.today()

days_since_sunday = (now.weekday()-6) % 8

last_sunday = now -timedelta(days=days_since_sunday)

formatted_date = last_sunday.strftime('%#m %d_%Y')

file_path = r"C:\Users\adoucette\DOT_Weekly\sqlexec.xlsx"

new_file_path = "C:\\Users\\adoucette\\DOT_Weekly\\DOT Weekly Sales WE " + formatted_date + ".xlsx"

# while not os.path.exists(file_path):

# print("File does not exist. Waiting...")

# time.sleep(5)

# shutil.move(file_path,new_file_path)

wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\adoucette\\DOT_Weekly\\DOT Weekly Sales WE " + formatted_date + ".xlsx",data_only=True)

# Select the desired sheet

ws = wb["Sheet1"]

start_cell = "A1"

end_cell = "AP1"

# Iterate through the range of cells and modify fill and font

for row in ws[start_cell:end_cell]:

for cell in row:

# Create a new PatternFill and Font object for each cell

fill = PatternFill(start_color='305496', end_color='305496', fill_type='solid')

font_style = Font(name="Calibri", size=11, bold=True, italic=False, color="fcfcfc")

# Assign the fill and font styles to the cell

cell.fill = fill

cell.font = font_style

wb.save("C:\\Users\\adoucette\\DOT_Weekly\\DOT Weekly Sales WE " + formatted_date + ".xlsx")
```

I tried using different engines to open the file, converting it over to CSV. All of this hinges on being able to open the file before anything else is done.

The code works if you open the file and save immediately after, but that defeats the purpose of the project I am working on.

Comment: The source file contains some invalid OOXML.